# How do i make a calculated field in access which is the sum of data from a query?

Tags: forms, ms-access, ms-access-2013, calculated-field

I have these 3 tables:

job(**job_num**, job_cost)

item(**item_id**, item_name)

job_line(**job_num**, **item_id**, cost)

Now in access i have a form that deals with the job table and a subform within that form that deals with job_line. job_line is to allow multiple items to be on a single job record(job_line is the relational table).

Now I am trying to get job_cost in the main form to be a calculated field where by is sums the costs in the result set for job_line.

EG:

table:job

```
job_num : 3
job_cost : 0
```

table:job_line

```
job_num : 3
item_id : 1
cost : 100

job_num :3 
item_id : 2
cost : 50
```

Therefore i wish that job_cost would dynamically update to 150 to reflect the sum of the two entries within job_line.

I am using Microsoft Access 2013.

Comment: see the tables but do not see the Query you are referencing.....

Answer (score 0):

Since I do not see your actual query I will give you an example of how to calculate the total cost in the SQL view.  The key is the second select statement which calculates the field and displays it as a column.

```
SELECT job_line.job_num, job_line.item_id, (Select Sum( job_line.cost) from job_line) AS TotalCost
FROM job_line
Group by job_line.job_num, job_line.item_num;
```

Comment: Ive been trying similar things all day, and i keep getting the #NAME? error in my field. I even renamed all my fields to just 'textbox1/2/3' etc.